# Why doesn't FindWindowEx find IP Address window?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Created an IP address window as follows, then tried to find it using `FindWindowEx` function:

```
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;
    icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icex.dwICC = ICC_INTERNET_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    // hwnd is the parent of the IP address window
    HWND eIpAddress = CreateWindowW(WC_IPADDRESS,
        L"ServerIpAddress",
        WS_CHILD | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE,
        MulDiv(LOWORD(units), 40, 4), 50,
        MulDiv(LOWORD(units), 70, 4),
        MulDiv(HIWORD(units), 11, 8),
        hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // try to retrieve the control; does not work, returns null
    HWND wnd_server_ipaddress = FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, NULL, L"ServerIpAddress");

    DWORD err = GetLastError(); // --> returns 0
```

But `wnd_server_ipaddress` is NULL. I'm doing the exact same thing with two other standard edit windows that have different names and it's working. Looked in Spy++ to ensure the hierarchy is correct and it is. Added `GetLastError()` after the call and it returns 0.

```
        // works
        HWND wnd_server_name = FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, NULL, L"ServerName");

        // does not work
        HWND wnd_server_ipaddress = FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, WC_IPADDRESS, L"ServerIpAddress");
        HWND wnd_server_ipaddress2 = FindWindow(WC_IPADDRESS, L"ServerIpAddress");

        // works
        wchar_t server_name[512] = { 0 };
        GetWindowText(wnd_server_name, server_name, 512);

        // does not work because wnd_server_ipaddress is null
        wchar_t server_ipaddress[16] = { 0 };
        DWORD dwAddr = 0x0;
        int iCount = (int)SendMessage(wnd_server_ipaddress, IPM_GETADDRESS, 0, (LPARAM)&dwAddr);
        _snwprintf_s(server_ipaddress, sizeof(server_ipaddress) / sizeof(*server_ipaddress), 16,
            L"%ld.%ld.%ld.%ld",
            (dwAddr >> 24) & 0xff,
            (dwAddr >> 16) & 0xff,
            (dwAddr >> 8)  & 0xff,
            (dwAddr)       & 0xff);
```

**Question:** is there something specific to `WC_IPADDRESS` that causes `FindWindowEx` not to find the control?

---

**Edit**
Added code that works for standard control.

```
    // creation with ServerName as lpWindowName
    HWND eName = CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"ServerName",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,
        MulDiv(LOWORD(units), 40, 4), 10,
        MulDiv(LOWORD(units), 150, 4),
        MulDiv(HIWORD(units), 11, 8),
        hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // reset text
    SetWindowText(eName, L"");

    // retrieve control - works
    HWND wnd_server_name = FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, NULL, L"ServerName");

    // retrieve value - works, gets whatever the text in the control is
    wchar_t server_name[512] = { 0 };
    GetWindowText(wnd_server_name, server_name, 512);
```

Comment: To the downvoter: could you please explain what exactly is wrong with this question?

Comment: Your use of `FindWindowEx()` on standard Edit controls will fail as soon as the user changes the content of the edit fields.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added the whole code for the standard edit control. Not sure if we're talking about the same thing but it does not fail. It works with changing the content of the field, I retrieve what the user types in there.

Comment: the only way that code could work is if there was another edit control with `ServerName` as its text content. Double check that `CreateWindow()` and `FindWindowEx()` are returning the same `HWND`. Like I said in another comment, there are no window names in the Win32 API. A window is identified by its `HWND` or by a parent/child ID, not by a name string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [IP Address control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/ip-address-control-reference) is [not a standard edit control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/ip-address-controls#is-an-ip-address-control-an-edit-control). Assigning window text like `"ServerIpAddress"` to an IP Address control is meaningless, and it is likely being discarded during the window creation. To assign an IP address to an IP Address control, you must use the [`IPM_SETADDRESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/ipm-setaddress) window message.

Also, per the [`FindWindowEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexw) documentation:

> If the `lpszWindow` parameter is not NULL, `FindWindowEx` calls the `GetWindowText` function to retrieve the window name for comparison.

`GetWindowText()` does not work with an IP Address control, like it does for a standard edit control.  To retrieve an IP address from an IP Address control, you must use the [`IPM_GETADDRESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/ipm-getaddress) window message.

As such, when using `FindWindow/Ex()`, an IP Address control cannot be found by its textual content, like a standard edit control can be. It can only be found by its `WC_IPADDRESS` class name.

To do what you are trying, you need to either:

1. save the `HWND` of the IP Address control that `CreateWindow()` returns (this is the preferred solution):

   ```c
   HWND gIpAddress; // stored somewhere that you can reach it

   ...

   // hwnd is the parent of the IP address window
   gIpAddress = CreateWindowW(WC_IPADDRESS,
       L"",
       WS_CHILD | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE,
       MulDiv(LOWORD(units), 40, 4), 50,
       MulDiv(LOWORD(units), 70, 4),
       MulDiv(HIWORD(units), 11, 8),
       hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

   ...

   DWORD dwAddr = 0x0;
   SendMessage(gIpAddress, IPM_GETADDRESS, 0, (LPARAM)&dwAddr);
   ...
   ```
2. specify a *Control ID* for the IP Address control (in the `hMenu` parameter of `CreateWindow()`), and then use [`GetDlgItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitem) to get the `HWND` of the IP Address control when needed:

   ```c
   // hwnd is the parent of the IP address window
   HWND eIPAddress = CreateWindowW(WC_IPADDRESS,
       L"",
       WS_CHILD | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE,
       MulDiv(LOWORD(units), 40, 4), 50,
       MulDiv(LOWORD(units), 70, 4),
       MulDiv(HIWORD(units), 11, 8),
       hwnd, (HMENU)12345, NULL, NULL);

   ...

   // hwnd is the parent of the IP address window
   HWND wnd_server_ipaddress = GetDlgItem(hwnd, 12345);
   DWORD dwAddr = 0x0;
   SendMessage(wnd_server_ipaddress, IPM_GETADDRESS, 0, (LPARAM)&dwAddr);
   ...
   ```

Comment: I was not trying to set the text, I was trying to set the window name, to be able to find it later. I updated the question: I am using `IPM_GETADDRESS` but it does not work because I need to send the window handle. So question is how can I find that window handle (later, in a click button handler)? Should I keep a reference to it at global level while the parent window is open?

Comment: Using a `g_wndipaddress`at main.c file level and storing a reference to the control there when window opens worked. But still would like to know if there is a way to retrieve the IP address without using a global variable. Also I don't understand what you mean by _text content_, I though parameters were only "class name" and "window title".

Comment: @supafly "*I was not trying to set the text, I was trying to set the window name*" - you can't assign a name to a window, that is not what the `lpWindowName` parameter is actually for, despite its name. Read the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindoww): "*If the window style specifies a title bar, the **window title** pointed to by `lpWindowName` is displayed in the title bar. When using `CreateWindow` to create controls, such as buttons, check boxes, and static controls, **use `lpWindowName` to specify **the text of the control**.*"

Comment: @supafly "*how can I find that window handle (later, in a click button handler)?*" - if you don't save the `HWND` you create, then you would have to enumerate the parent's controls looking at their class names until you find the IP Address control. You can use `FindWindowEx()` for that, or `EnumChildWindows()` calling `GetClassName()` in its callback. "*Should I keep a reference to it at global level while the parent window is open?*" - yes, of course you should keep a reference to the `HWND` you create, if you plan on interacting with it at all. Don't hunt for it when you don't need to.

Comment: @supafly alternatively, if you don't want to save the `HWND` of the IP Address control, then you can instead assign a **Child Control ID** (via the `hMenu` parameter of `CreateWindow()` when using the `WS_CHILD` style) to the IP Address control, and then use [`GetDlgItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitem) when needed to get the control's `HWND` from its ID, if you have access to the parent's `HWND`.  I updated my answer to show that.

Comment: Ok, I was trying to avoid a 'global' variable, but my `g_wndipaddress` looks like your solution 1 if I got it right. However regarding the `lpWindowName` I'll edit my question to show you what I did for a standard edit field and somehow, works. Thank you for the answer, and for your patience.